# Best way to support "Extendable enums" in annotations?

Tags: java, enums, annotations

In my library there is a concept of "user levels". I have provided several default levels but for various reasons want to give the user the option of using their own levels.

Currently this is implemented as

```
public interface AdminLevel {
    public void name();
}

public enum StandardAdminLevels implements AdminLevel {
    ADMIN,
    ANONYMOUS
}
```

The problem is that the user is usually going to be passing their required user level in an annotation. Things I have tried and failed:

- Using AdminLevel as the type - Fails with "invalid type for annotation member"
- Using String as the type but setting the value with `StandardAdminLevels.ADMIN.name()` - Fails with "attribute value must be constant"
- Making StandardAdminLevels a final class that doesn't implement anything with public static final field's for each of the levels (essentially an enum) - Fails with "invalid type for annotation member"

Is there any other way I can't think of to have extendable enums in annotations? I'm trying to stick with enums due to their clarity and basic protection against invalid values, but the only other way I can think of is String constants. The problem I have is that would require verification at every single point user levels are used, potentially even in client code

Any ideas?

Comment: An extensible enum is a contradiction in terms.  The entire purpose of enums is to define the entire set and only allow those.

Comment: @Aurand How are magic strings or magic ints better though? Enums are still useful here for validation of values

Comment: What's wrong with having one enum with all possible values?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda I am wanting users to be able to add their own admin levels. A predefined enum prevents that

Comment: So you have two options only then. Either a class like suggested by @Sebastian Redl or a String value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One idea: every possible AdminLevel is its own class. Pass the `Class` of that class to the annotation.

```
public final class Admin implements AdminLevel { ... }
public final class Anonymous implements AdminLevel { ... }

@Requires(Admin.class) public void protectedMethod() { ... }

@interface Requires {
  Class<? extends AdminLevel> value();
}
```

Comment: Woah, that's actually not a bad idea. The classes could even implement Comparable and therefore be user sortable

Comment: Good thinking, but I'm not sure I see the advantage over plain strings.

Comment: @Paul Automatic validation ("sadfakjdsf" isn't automatically an admin level) and user sortability. I'll see if there are other idea's, but this is a pretty good one

Comment: @TheLQ Yeah, the compile time checking is attractive +1

Comment: Be wary of trying to implement Comparable (or any sorting really) on freely extensible things. Aside from not being obvious (is "UserThatCanOnlySubmitDamageReports" before or after "UserThatCanOnlyWriteReviewsForDamageReports"?), it's also a code maintenance nightmare. I add a new role, and I now have to add a comparison to every single other role? In a modular system, where plug-ins can add roles at will, that's just impossible.

Comment: To make them easily comparable, an option is just include a numeric field "order", and compare via order / then name. So the user only needs to take car of using big integers (1000, 2000, 3000), and be happy inserting in between as needed. Every once in a while, a full re order make things prettier

Comment: Note that you'll get a `Class<? extends AdminLevel>` object. You'll need to instantinate an `AdminLevel` object via reflection to compare the levels. I understand that user will provide a pluggable JAR that contains some functionality and additional admin level classes?